# Gridstack JS Nested Grid clickable icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

Is there any option/s needed so the icons inside nested grid will be clickable?

I have an icon on the parent grid and it's working fine, but when it comes to the icons inside nested grid, nothing happens.

[image]

```
<div class="grid-stack parent-grid">

    <div class="grid-stack-item wid-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-no-move="true">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content wid-item-content">

            <div class="widget-container">
                <div class="widget-title">
                    <span id="wid-title">WIDGET TITLE</span>
                    <span class="widget-icon icon-enlarge"></span>
                    <span class="widget-icon icon-bin"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-body">

                    <div class="grid-stack widget-component">
                        <div class='grid-stack-item wid-component-item'>
                            <div class='grid-stack-item-content'>
                                <div class='widget-title'>
                                    <span class='widget-icon icon-bin'></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class='widget-body'>
                                    <label>Widget 1</label> <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".icon-bin").click(function (e) {
        alert("ASD");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @dllhell hi I included the codes

Comment: Can you post reference to this icons so icon can be shown? If I put icon awesome it works, if I put content within span - it works